# I want to mix old latex paint with ready concrete mix or cat litter to make pavers.

Tags: paint, cement, pavers

I want to mix latex paint with ready mix concrete or cat litter to make pavers. Trying to find a way of using approx 200 gallons of old paint since I can't dispose it. Also trying to come up with inexpensive pavers.

Comment: While I could see the possibility of turning ready mix concrete + paint into colorful pavers (just needing an expert opinion as to how to do it successfully), I can't see any way that cat litter - which is designed to NOT become a solid object - could be used in that way.

Comment: Have you talked with Habitat for Humanity?   As far as disposal, an old country boy conservationist said "Paint something you don't want, then throw it away". I disposed of probably 15 half-gallons of old paint in our basement when a builder next door left a bunch of damaged drywall sheets in a construction dumpster.  They went to the dump 15 different colors...

Comment: @Harper the ingenuity of how people get around the endless logic of protection..  :-)  , goes to show that if it is made easy people will do it, make it hard and they will find another way..

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this seems like more of a "life hacks".SE question.  There are how-to guides "all over the web" about **tinting concrete with latex paint** (normal mix, except when adding water, replace 25% of the water with latex paint). While the *intent* is not yours and they are obviously running out and buying paint for this purpose, the *effect* is the same.

Despite your eagerness to make the paint go away, I would not increase the ratio further unless you want the concrete to fail.  If you think it's a hassle to dispose of 3000 pounds of paint, try disposing of 50,000 pounds of concrete.

You may want stronger tints.  You can *up-tint* paint: adding more tints than are already in the can. - more yellow, or if yellow, some green/blue to make it greener.   Don't try to overpower tints with contradictory tints (ones on the other side of the color wheel), as the combination will **turn to mud**.   You'd need to find a family hardware store small enough not to have "policy" against selling you tints compatible with your system.

Answer (score 0):

Well you do not mention where in the world that you are located, nor do you mention how you attempted to dispose of it that you were denied or unable ?? Also you do not mention if you are a business or a consumer (200 gallons sounds like a business).

So there are a couple ways to do it:

1: If the paint is in good usable order - Donate it to a Habitat for Humanity Restore store.

2: If you live in the United States and are Located in a reasonably well inhabited part of civilization ,I guess if your town has a walmart you are in civilization. ;-)  . Check with your local community [generally the county] waste drop off ask for Household Hazardous Waste [HHW] - for that quantity you might need to pay a fee (10 gallons is easy and considered normal household, 200 gallons means there is no way you are a consumer).

You might find out how much you are allowed to drop off at a time - make several trips over the period of months.

Just an Additional note - a synopsis from [here ^](https://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/home-diy/painting/how-to-dispose-of-paint2.htm) :

Individuals with old paint should contact their local Keep America Beautiful affiliate to find out if they would take paint donations for graffiti cleanups, or contact their local chapter of Habitat for Humanity," advises environmental educator Denise Carleton of Reaping Nature Productions.

Plenty of other local organizations would be happy to accept your left-over paint. Art teachers, summer camps, and non-profit organizations such as Boy Scouts, 4-H and the Salvation Army can use a potpourri of paint colors for murals, activities, service projects and to spruce up donated items. High school or community theatre groups can use it for stage sets. Just make sure they know to limit the use of exterior paints to well-ventilated outdoor projects. You can also check with local government departments such as parks, buildings and maintenance, fire departments, military bases or prisons to see if they're interested in free paint.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is about mixing paint and concrete / cat litter

Comment: It's true, you are allowed to ["structure" (smurf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring) your recyclable drop-offs in order to evade maximum limits.  I already smurf my trash; I give the city 1-2 trash bags a week instead of 80 bags on December 31.  The SEC hasn't kicked down my door yet.

Comment: @Harper I am thinking from some of your comments that a more lucrative field for you might be in stand up, cause you have me laughing again... thanx .. LOL.   :-)